# git request code review from command line git pull

Tags: git, version-control

I am using our shared repository, when i need to merge my changes in, I have to request a merge pull request from github page,which will be checked be a reviwer before it can be pushed up.

A simple git pull from the command line results in :

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: At least one approved review is required by reviewers with write access.
```

Example:

I have a local master, and a local feature branch

I checkeout master, I pull in changes from feature branch

Now local master is behind the origin master by 1 commit

I want to push to master, i use git push

I receive the error below, this is because we a have review policy on the repository.

Can I request a pull request via command line?

Comment: Is git pull or git push which gives you error? To create a pull request, you first create a new branch from master branch, then commit changes to the new branch, push the new branch to github online and then create a pull request there to merge changed from the new branch to master branch.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya please see the updated question

Comment: The approach I suggested is the exact solution to the problem you described. You need to push changes of feature branch to origin first and then create pull request to merge changes from feature branch to master branch. Once pull request is approve, you can merge the pull request. Then you can do git pull from local to get the merged changes from origin master to local master.

Comment: I am doing this, i push from featurebranch local to featurebranch origin, then i pull those changes in origin featurebranch to local master and attempt to push to origin master but i cannot do it via command prompt, as it stops me from doing so. I have to use github online to do that final step

Comment: You should create pull request online from origin featurebranch to origin master branch. Github online should have a button `Create Pull Request` which need to create pull request. You can not create pull request from command line.

Comment: ah okay, that is fine. I am doing that, just wondered if there was an option to do this via command prompt

Answer (score 3):

With the recent [cli/cli](https://github.com/cli/cli) (GitHub command line), you can:

- [mark a PR ready for review](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/960)
- review, approve and merge a PR, [all from the command-line](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v0.9.0)!

For instance:

```
$ gh pr checkout 123
$ gh pr diff
$ gh pr review --approve -b "lgtm"
$ gh pr merge
```

Note: [GitHub CLI 2.4.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.4.0) (Dec. 2021) adds:

> `pr merge`: allow editing commit subject

Comment: That's great! Will definitely be using this

Comment: please @VonC, one link is incorrect, can you fix that?

Comment: @ElDavid Sure, thank you for reporting it: I have fixed the incorrect link.